# How to fix a HTTP 500 error caused by activating W3 Total Cache plugin?

Tags: wordpress, w3-total-cache

I installed and activated the W3 Total Cache plugin for WordPress, but then immediately had a 500 error appear on the admin panel. The site is up and running fine but I can't access the plugins to deactivate it.

Has anyone got a solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Login to your site’s files using the file manager provided by your host or use FTP program such as Filezilla to see files/folders.
2. Browse to the /wp-content/plugins/ folder.
3. Find the folder of the plugin you wish to disable.
4. Rename that folder as w3-total-cache.deactivate
5. Once you do this, The plugin will be deactivated.

Comment: Thank you - that worked perfectly. Do you know what causes that failure with the activation of a plugin? If it didn't work I would assume that there would be something about that somewhere so I'm assuming that it's something to do with my site...

Comment: Probably it may have conflict with other plugins, How many plugins your site has ? 
Do one thing if there are less number of plugins.
- deactivate one plugin from backend 
- Activate w3total-cache
Do this few times to debug the cauase,
Probably you will find out if any plugin is causing the issue.
Other possibility is File permission.

Answer (score 1):

If you have FTP access than simply rename the W3 Total Cache plugin folder.
You can find it under `/wp-content/plugins/` directory.